# Responsive video don't adjust as expected

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, video, responsive-design

My main goal was archieved, i wanted to have a background video on the top of my page but the problem now is that i want the video to be responsive, it kinda is responsive but in the wrong way, when i decrease the screen the video gets smaller, instead of increase the height, what just happens is that the width and the height get smaller i just want the width to get smaller and the height to increase.

Here is a example:

**Current behaviour:**

[image: Current behaviour]

**What i need:**
[image: What i want]

**My html code:**

```
<section class="custom content_section bg_fixed white_section bg2">
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">


            <div id="video_overlays"></div>

            <div class="container vertical-center">
                <div id="over">
                    <div class="title-wrapper main_title  centered upper">
                        <h2 id="video_title"><span class="line"></span>VIDEO TITLE</h2>
                    </div>

                    <div class="description4 centered">
                        <p id="video_sub_title"><b>LOREM IPSUM A SIMPLE DESCRIPTION<br>
Usability and simple deployment are the key words.</b></p>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="player" width="100%" height="100%" style="z-index:-1">
            </div>
        </div>

    </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example:

http://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/YVKNdr

Try the following styling for the div holding your video. The important bits are that you set min-height and min-width to 100%, then use transform:translate to center the video.

Hope this helps!

**CSS**

```
#player {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%; left: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: doesn't work :S same effect, i tried to apply that on the parent div, but the video just dissapears

Comment: please see updae above @FilipeCosta

Comment: almost solvet, i need to delete my classes embed-responsive and the aspect ratio 1, but still got 1 problem with the aspect ratio now, when i decrease the size i see the black borders at top and bottom, is there a simple way to correct this?

Comment: Hey @FilipeCosta, create a fork of my codepen, make your changes and I'll look at them when I have a chance.

Answer (score 0):

Try This one

**CSS**

```
#videocontainer{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:-1;
    background:url(../the link to image when video uploads or not supported by browser.jpg) center center no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.videobg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: -100;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    background-size: cover;
    transition: 1s opacity;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

**Your HTML**

```
<div class="videocontainer>
    <video class="videobg" controls autoplay loop id=player  poster="http://the link to image when video uploads or not supported by browser" >
        <source src="link to your mp4 video file.mp4" type="video/mp4" >
    </video>
</div>
```